# Using x86 style jump table in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, jump-table

I am trying to do a jump table in **C** like this

```
    cmp     eax, dword 3                        ;max number
    ja      invalid                     ;default
    jmp     [eax*4+jumptable]           ;jump to handler
invalid:
    retn
jumptable:
    dd handle0, handle1, handle2, handle3
handle0:
    ....
```

and so forth

I started with this

```
void dohandler(int a, int b, void (*jumptable[4]) (int x))
    if (a > 3) return
    else jumptable[3 * 4](b);
}
int main() {
    void (*jumptable[4]) (int x);
    jumptable[0] = &handler1;
    ... etc

    dohandler(1,2,jumptable);
}
void handler1(int x) { ... }
.. etc
```

but its not working well..

Comment: What did the `switch` statement ever do to you?

Comment: You should decide whether you want to program in C or in ASM, and then do so.

Comment: switch.. is not as flexible as I need for this project
for example, a switch statement of 300 cases is not ideal..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but I think you have a couple of problems here:

```
void dohandler(int a, int b, void (*jumptable[4]) (int x))
    if (a > 3) return
    else jumptable[3 * 4](b);
}
```

First, you don't use `a` in referencing your jump table, and I think that corresponds to the `eax` register in the assembly version. Second, don't multiply that by 4. I think that's intended to be the size of a pointer, and the array reference does that for you. So you end up with this:

```
void dohandler(int a, int b, void (*jumptable[4]) (int x))
    if (a > 3) return
    else jumptable[a](b);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`jumptable` is an array of pointers.  Don't try to scale the offset, just index which pointer you want to reference.

```
void dohandler(int a, int b, void (*jumptable[4]) (int x))
    if (a >= 0 && a < 4)
        jumptable[a](b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`switch` will get compiled to a jumptable just like you want as long as the label values aren't too sparse. It may help to have a small size type (like `unsigned char`) for the expression, or to mask off the high bits, so the compiler doesn't add an extra "if-in-range" conditional before the jumptable jump, but that might not be so important.

Most importantly, experiment. Use `gcc -S` to examine the assembly output.

Comment: I would use a switch but I have over 300 cases that are in sequential order from 0 to 299

Comment: Does the compiler fail to generate a jumptable for the switch?

Comment: Seems most compilers are a bit flaky at this wish there was a flag you could use to force it and accept the "consequences" that it's trying to avoid if any.